# Remove white bar at the top of the page - Wordpress theme Lounge

Tags: html, css, wordpress

At my website http://bookofrakostenlosspielen.org/ I'm using Wordpress Theme [Lounge](https://themeforest.net/item/lounge-clean-elegant-wordpress-theme/4616086). But there is white bar at the top of all pages. How could I remove it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Please take a chance to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posing another question. This is not what would be considered a good question, as you have not provided any code to recreate your issue and once you've fixed it on your website, readers will not be able to see the issue you were having.

That said you can add this CSS to hide the white bar:

```
.header_top_outer {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
.header_top_outer {
     display: none !important;
}
```

To the bottom of the `style.css` file in the editor, under the Appearance tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.header_top_outer{display:none;}
```

Or better still remove that element if you're not using it.